# PrimefacesCommandbuttons not calling Backing Bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but this is a unique case. One `<h:form>` has multiple `<p:commandButton>`. One used to work before, now nothing works. It's a submit action, so i cannot use `immediate="true"` on them. But when  I do, for testing it calls the backing bean. But when  `immediate="false"`, it does not read even a `System.out.println("");` in the backing bean. This issue has happened before and I resolved it by deleting the .jsf and reconstructing it from scratch. But it's not working now. Please help !

Comment: Sure your problem is not covered by point 3 of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183?

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to include some example code. The error "not working" is to broad and there is a variety of reasons why a commandButton might not invoke its action method.

Comment: Tried different things, but it finally worked when I deleted the .jsf and tried it again from scratch ! Thanks.